# Compile error IEEE access template using algorithm2e package

Tags: algorithm2e, ieeeaccess

I have been trying for a while to load the algorithm2e package to the IEEE ACCESS template. Whenever I use the following code, I am getting the error

```
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
% \usepackage{algorithm, algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage[ruled, linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}


\begin{document}


\IncMargin{1em}
\begin{algorithm*}[!t]
    \caption{Caption}
    \DontPrintSemicolon
    \Indm 
        \KwIn{%
            Input 1 
        }%
    \Indp
    Statement 1 \;

\end{algorithm*}
\DecMargin{1em}


\EOD

\end{document}
```

Error is

```
Argument of \relsize  has an extra }. <inserted text> 
               \par  l.23     S
         tatement 1 \; Runaway argument?
```

If preamble `\usepackage[ruled, linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}` to `\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}`, above code works well, but following code doesn't compile with other error messages

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
% \usepackage{algorithm, algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}


\begin{document}


\IncMargin{1em}
\begin{algorithm*}[!t]
    \caption{Caption}
    \DontPrintSemicolon
    \Indm 
        \KwIn{%
            Input 1 
        }%
    \Indp
    Statement 1 \;
    \If{$a==1$}{
        aaa \;
    }

\end{algorithm*}
\DecMargin{1em}


\EOD

\end{document}
```

Error is

```
 Paragraph ended before \@algocf@endoption was complete. <to be read again> 
                   \par  l.27 \end
         {algorithm*}
```

Comment: Welcome top TeX:SE!

Comment: Both examples compiled for me with and without `linesnumbered` with no error. Which version of TexLive are you using? And which template (`ieeeaccess.cls` does not come with the TeXLive installation)

Comment: TeXLive version is 2019. `ieeeaccess.cls` was downloaded from the following URL: https://ieeeaccess.ieee.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/access.zip

Comment: I tested other cls (IEEEtran, etc...) the code can complie. So, I think alogorithm2e and ieeeaccess.cls combination is bad.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Algorithm2e with ieeeaccess](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/584728/algorithm2e-with-ieeeaccess) (It's weird, I know, this question is actually older but I hadn't seen it before...)