# Algorithm2e with ieeeaccess

Tags: algorithm2e, ieeeaccess

I am using overleaf. When using the `algorithm2e` package, it gives me bold line numbers prefixed with a "-" symbol for each line. I want to have a line number in small fonts without the "-" symbol. An output pdf snapshot is attached with minimal working code. Thank you in advance.

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
     \begin{algorithm}
    \DontPrintSemicolon   
    % enter the algorithm environment
    \caption{algorithm}          
    % give the algorithm a caption
    \label{alg1}   
    %\begin{multicols}{2}                       % and a label for \ref{} commands 
    %\begin{algorithmic}[1] 
    \KwIn{
        $a=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i\cdot2^i$,
        $b=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} b_i\cdot2^i$,
        $m=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} m_i\cdot2^i$}
    \KwOut {$c = a \times b$ \text{mod} $m$}
    
    $c \leftarrow 0, \quad reg_1 \leftarrow a$\;
    $reg \leftarrow 2a$ mod $m \qquad \text {//     \scriptsize Pre-computed value //} $\;
    %$N \leftarrow n+2 \quad \quad \quad \text{ //  \scriptsize append two 0's to left of MSB of y //}$\;
    $N= 
    \begin{cases}
    n+3,& \text{ if $n \bmod 2 = 0,$ append two $0$ to the left of MSB of $b$} \\
    n+2,& \text{ if $n \bmod 2 = 1,$ append single $0$ to the left of MSB of $b$}
    \end{cases}
    $\;
    $N \leftarrow N+1 \qquad  \text{ // \scriptsize append 0 to right of LSB of b //}$\;
    
    \For {$(i=0; i \leq N-2; i \leftarrow i+2)$ }{
        \Switch{$(b_{(i+2:i)})$}{
            \textbf{when} $ 000 \mid 111 \Longrightarrow v\leftarrow 0$ \;
            \textbf{when} $ 001 \mid 010 \mid 101 \mid 110 \Longrightarrow v\leftarrow reg_1$  \;
            \textbf{else} $ \Longrightarrow  d\leftarrow reg_2$ \;
        }
        \tcp {following critical operations are executed concurrently //}
        $reg_1 \leftarrow 4\times reg_1 \text{ modulo } m$\; 
        $reg_2 \leftarrow 4\times reg_2 \text{ modulo } m$\; 
        $v \leftarrow v \pm d \text{ modulo } m$\;
    }
    \Return{$v$}\;
    %\end{multicols}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ, which font packages you load, and how or where `\atcp` is defined.

Comment: Off-topic: I believe you should replace all instances of `\sum_{i=o}^{n-1}` with `\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}`.

Comment: I am using IEEE Access document class with following packages \documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}

Comment: This is not a MWE, please edit and complete with all preamble, in order to make it work for everyone just by copy/paste in our editor.

Comment: now i have edited it in the form of MWE...

Comment: yes I have to use IEEE access class...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the choice, use a different class.

If you don't, make a copy of the original `\textbf` before loading the class and restore it afterwards

```
\NewCommandCopy{\LaTeXtextbf}{\textbf}
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\RenewCommandCopy{\textbf}{\LaTeXtextbf}
% [ the rest of your document ]
```

or for formats older than the October 2020 release

```
\RequirePackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro{\LaTeXtextbf}{\textbf}
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\LetLtxMacro{\textbf}{\LaTeXtextbf}
% [ the rest of your document ]
```

[image]

---

### Explanation

The file `ieeeaccess.cls` does a lot of wonderful things, among which we find the following jewels (new lines added for clarity):

```
\def\textbf#1{{\bf #1}}%
\long\def\bf#1{%
   \ifmmode
      \mathbf{#1}%
      \message{Please use mathbf in math mode instead of bf.}%
   \else
      \fontencoding{T1}%
      \fontseries{b}%
      \selectfont{#1}%
   \fi
}
```

The first redefinition is very questionable but might be acceptable if `\bf` were defined in a sensible way. However, the actual definition of `\bf` is really evil and will break down every time the argument of `\textbf` starts with a macro taking arguments (or some primitive, or who knows what else).

Let us make a concrete example: assume we are in text mode and we write

```
\textbf{ABCDE...}
```

The first expansion turns this into

```
{\bf ABCDE...}
```

Now `\bf` has been defined *to take an argument*, which will be just the first token of the argument passed to `\textbf`, in this example `A`. The expansion of `\bf` turns then our example into

```
{\fontencoding{T1}\fontseries{b}\selectfont{A}BCDE...}
```

I suspect (though I'm not Mary Poppins and as such I might be incorrect) that the result isn't quite what the author(s) intended. The first token (here `A`) is put into a group, which will break kerning with the following letter.

---

The situation is even worse when the argument of `\textbf` involves other macros, like in the case of `algorithm2e`. The line numbers are printed using `\NlSty{\theAlgoLine}`, where `\theAlgoLine` expands to the line counter, and `\NlSty` is defined (simplifying a bit) as

```
\newcommand{\NlSty}[1]{\textbf{\relsize{-2}#1}}
```

This is similar to what I've written above, only that this time the first token of the argument  of `\textbf` isn't a letter but is rather `\relsize`. After expansion of the gloriously redefined `\textbf` and `\bf` the code `\NlSty{\theAlgoLine}` results in

```
{\fontencoding{T1}\fontseries{b}\selectfont{\relsize}{-2}\theAlgoLine}
```

The macro `\relsize` is enclosed in a group and chaos ensues.

Comment: You should change `\LetLtxMacro` with `\NewCommandCopy` and `\RenewCommandCopy`, maybe suggesting `\LetLtxMacro` for older TeX distributions.

Comment: @egreg Done. I was in fact wondering why I used `letltxmacro` even if `\NewCommandCopy` was already in the kernel in February 2021, but then it occurred to me that at that time my work desktop still had (well, it actually still has...) TeX Live 2017...