# algorithm2e showing errors in IEEE Access format ("Argument of \@algocf@endoption has an extra }. } "and "Paragraph ended before \@algocf@endoption")

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e, algorithmicx, algorithmic, ieeeaccess

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
    \history{Date of publication xxxx 00, 0000, date of current version xxxx 00, 0000.}
    \doi{--.----/ACCESS.2021.DOI}
    \title{Securing GA based Routing in an SDN for Blockchained Internet of Things}
    \author{\uppercase{xyz} \authorrefmark{1}, \uppercase{abc} \authorrefmark{1,*}, (\IEEEmembership{Senior Member, IEEE})} \address[1]{Great University World} \corresp{*Correspondence: xyz}
\titlepgskip=-15pt
\maketitle
\begin{algorithm}[h]
    \caption{LRA for Forwarding Nodes}
    \label{Authentication}
%   \SetAlgoLined
    \KwIn{$ID_{RN},~L_{RN},~Er_{RN}$} 
    \KwOut{Storing or Updating the Node's Credentials} 
    \KwResult{$ID_{RN},~L_{RN},~Er_{RN}$ }
    \eIf{$ID_{RN},~L_{RN}$ Not Stored in Blockchain}{
        \eIf{$Er_{RN} \ge threshold$ }
        {
             $ID_{RN},~L_{RN},~ En_{RN}$\;
        }
        {
            Reject\;
        }
    }
    {
         the $Er_{RN}$ if changed\;
    }
\end{algorithm}
\EOD
\end{document}
```

Comment: The first error that I get is that `algorithm` is already defined, and you shouldn't load both `algotirhm` and  `algorithm2e`. This being said, `ieeeaccess` is a very buggy class which shouldn't be used unless absolutely required, and there are many issues in its interaction with `algorithm2e`, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/584728/82917

Comment: I have tried both and all combinations using algorithm, algorithmic and algorithm2e, but problem still exist. I know about the problems, in my article I have long algorithms, which are hard to convert, thats why I am looking for the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file `ieeeaccess` is very badly written, and redefines some kernel macros (in this case `\textbf`) in a way which is bound to develop chaos. You should avoid it, if you can.

Don't load `algorithm` if you use `algorithm2e`: the latter already provides the facilities of the former. Note also that you need to explicitly load `graphicx`, because `ieeeaccess`uses its macros without actually checking that the package is loaded.

The solution is to make a copy of the original `\textbf` before loading the class, and restoring this definition afterwards. (Shameless self-publicity:  [Algorithm2e with ieeeaccess](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/584728/82917).)

```
\RequirePackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro{\LaTeXtextbf}{\textbf}
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\LetLtxMacro{\textbf}{\LaTeXtextbf}

\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[h]
    \caption{LRA for Forwarding Nodes}
    \label{Authentication}
%   \SetAlgoLined
    \KwIn{$ID_{RN},~L_{RN},~Er_{RN}$} 
    \KwOut{Storing or Updating the Node's Credentials} 
    \KwResult{$ID_{RN},~L_{RN},~Er_{RN}$ }
    \eIf{$ID_{RN},~L_{RN}$ Not Stored in Blockchain}{
        \eIf{$Er_{RN} \ge threshold$ }
        {
             $ID_{RN},~L_{RN},~ En_{RN}$\;
        }
        {
            Reject\;
        }
    }
    {
         the $Er_{RN}$ if changed\;
    }
\end{algorithm}
\EOD
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Its realy appriciated. Now its working.

Comment: @Campa The answer campa provide works. An absolute master